# can $x^2+a=y^2$ where a is prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let a sequence of the sum of prime numbers be $S_1=2$, $S_2=5$, $S_3=10$, $S_4=17...$

Can $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ both be square numbers $x^2$ and $y^2$ respectively?

I have already made the observation that $x^2+a=y^2$

$a=(y+x)(y-x)$

and therefore $y-x=1$ and $x+y=a$ for this to hold.

Comment: The answer to the title question is yes. Notice that $9^2-8^2=17$, which is prime. This doesn't imply whether or not $S$ can have squares at all, much less consecutive squares, though.

Comment: The title omits x and y prime.  However your analysis leads to the conclusion y=3 and x=2 is the only solution..

Comment: For any odd prime $a=2k+1$, let $x=k$ and $y=k+1$.  Then $x^2+a=y^2$.

Comment: So your question is equivalent to can $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_{k-1}=\left(\frac{p_k-1}2\right)^2$?  As the right hand side is at least of the order $p_{k-1}^2/4$, maybe you could try to show that the left hand side is smaller for sufficiently large $k$, using the prime number theorem.  Perhaps $\sum_{n=1}^{p_{k-1}} \frac n{\ln(n)}$ is an estimate for the left hand side?

Comment: @herbsteinberg there is no condition that $x,y$ must be primes. But there are other conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S_n=x^2$, and $S_{n+1}=y^2,$ then, as you’ve noticed, $y+x=p_{n+1}, y-x=1.$ Solving these equations:

$$y=\frac{p_{n+1}+1}2,x=\frac{p_{n+1}-1}2$$

This also means that you need $$S_n=\left(\frac{p_{n+1}-1}2\right)^2.$$

Now for $n\geq 5:$

$$\begin{align}S_n&<1+3+5+7+9+11+\cdots +p_n\\&= \left(\frac{p_n+1}2\right)^2\\&\leq\left(\frac{p_{n+1}-1}2\right)^2\end{align}$$
(Where the first sum is the sum of the odd numbers from $1$ to $p_n,$ where the sum of the first $k$ odd numbers is known to be $k^2.$)

So there are no example $n\geq 5.$

You just need to check $n=1,2,3,4$ by hand.

Comment: As soon as I made my comment, I realised that the prime number theorem was overkill, and the fact that primes (other than 2) are odd should suffice for the inequality, but you pinned down the details faster than me (+1).

Comment: @tkf Yeah I'm only a yr 9 student so as soon as I saw the prime number theorem I was like wha?

Comment: in the second part of your answer I don't understand the part where you set x and y as (p_(n+1)-1)/2 and (p_(n-1)+1)/2?

Comment: Do you know how to  solve the equations $y+x=a,y-x=b?$ Add them together, you get $2y=a+b,$ subtract them and you get $2x=a-b.$ @TomXia

Comment: oh okay I read the response one more time, makes sense thanks! That was embarrassing, made it seem I didn't even know linear algebra.